# Dynamic stat_function changing inside ShinyApp

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

My goal is to build a simple ShinyApp that allows users to display a specific one variable function on the plot by typing its formula, e.g.`x^2`, inside a `shiny::textInput`. I'm trying to build this up with `ggplot2::stat_funcion` but unfortunately I was not able to find a solution since then.

**My code**

```
  library(tidyverse)
  library(plotly)
  library(shiny)
  library(shinydashboard)

  ui <- dashboardPage(
    
          dashboardHeader(title = h4(HTML("Title<br/>Subtitle"))),
          
          dashboardSidebar(textInput("function1", "Function")),
          
          dashboardBody(
            fluidRow(box(title = h4(HTML("Chart title")),
                         plotlyOutput("chart", height = 250)))
          )
          
        )
   
  
  server <- function(input, output) {
    
    MyFunction <- function(x) {x}
    func <- reactive({MyFunction(input$function1)}) 
    
    output$chart <- renderPlotly({
      
                    ggplotly(
                      chart = ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 15)), aes(x)) +
                        stat_function(fun = func, 
                                      geom = "line", size = 1, show.legend = F) + 
                        scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-100, 100)) 
                    )
                
                    })
    
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text input needs to be converted to an expression and evaluated

`eval(parse(text = input$function1))`

Otherwise it's just a character string.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = h4(HTML("Title<br/>Subtitle"))),
  dashboardSidebar(textInput("function1", "Function", value = "x^2")),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(box(
      title = h4(HTML("Chart title")),
      plotlyOutput("chart", height = 250)
    ))
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$chart <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(
      p = ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 15)), aes(x)) +
        stat_function(
          fun = function(x) eval(parse(text = input$function1)),
          geom = "line", size = 1, show.legend = F
        ) +
        scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-100, 100))
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```